# OIOSAML / SAML2 Attribute/Attribute value defining type?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, saml-2.0

Im trying to create a SAML2 ticket by using OIOSAML.net.

I have gotten 95% of the structure correct, however when creating the xml I have the following problem.

Result:

```
<saml2:Attribute name="urn:x:names:federation:attributeName:systemversion" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
            <saml2:AttributeValue>1.0</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

Expected:

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="urn:x:names:federation:attributeName:systemversion" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">1.0</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

I am missing the type definition on my AttributeValue. From the object definition I can read out the following.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the attribute value.
/// Contains a value of the attribute. If an attribute contains more than one discrete value, it is
/// RECOMMENDED that each value appear in its own &lt;AttributeValue&gt; element. If more than
/// one &lt;AttributeValue&gt; element is supplied for an attribute, and any of the elements have a
/// datatype assigned through xsi:type, then all of the &lt;AttributeValue&gt; elements must have
/// the identical datatype assigned.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The attribute value.</value>
[XmlElement("AttributeValue", IsNullable = true)]
public string[] AttributeValue
{
    get { return attributeValueField; }
    set { attributeValueField = value; }
}
```

And im defining the Attribute as follows:

```
var attr = new SamlAttribute() {
    Name = StringConstants.SAML2_ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX + StringConstants.ATTRIBUTE_INFO_SYSTEMVERSION,
    AttributeValue = new[] {this.SystemVersion},
    NameFormat = StringConstants.ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT
};
```

**Question**
How can I get my `<AttributeValue>` to define `xsi:type="xs:string"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a custom serialization object due to SP not handling parse from XSAnyImpl.

To acheive this I had to add some stuff into the SamlAttribute that worked for my specific case. I'm certain there should be a better solution available but this worked for my case.

**First ignore default value in serialization**

```
[XmlIgnore]
[XmlElement("AttributeValue", IsNullable = true)]
public string[] AttributeValue
{
    get { return attributeValueField; }
    set { attributeValueField = value; }
}
```

**Add new custom object**

```
[XmlElement("AttributeValue", IsNullable = true)]
public ExtendedAttributeValue[] Values { get; set; }


public class ExtendedAttributeValue {
        [XmlAttribute("type", DataType = "string", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Force type to xs:string**

```
new SamlAttribute() {
                    Name = StringConstants.SAML2_ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX + StringConstants.ATTRIBUTE_INFO_SYSTEMVERSION,
                    Values = new [] {new SamlAttribute.ExtendedAttributeValue(){Type = "xs:string",Value = this.SystemVersion}},
                    NameFormat = StringConstants.ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT
};
```

**Result**

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="urn:x:names:federation:attributeName:systemversion" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
        <saml2:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">1.0</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

**xs & xsi defined in root node**

```
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
```